# How to share values between batch file and embedded script

Tags: batch-file, embed

I am trying to share values between my batch file and embedded script within it and I can't find a way to make it work. I am relatively new to embedded scripting...

I have tried to find an answer on the web and I can't find an answer to my question. It would need to be (all the scripts) in the same .bat file...

```
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cls
set "Shared_UserName=VelocityDK"
goto ShareValue

:ShareValue
cls
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:UserName
pause >nul
cls & exit /force

----- Begin wsf script --->
<package>
    <job id="UserName">
        <script language="VBScript">
            Dim Shared_UserName As String = %Shared_UserName%
            WScript.Echo "Your username is: " & Shared_UserName
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

I am expecting the embedded VBScript to write the following output: `Your username is VelocityDK.` but instead, I get a message saying:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Comment: What exactly do you want to transport in what direction? from batch to wsf an easy way was command line parameters...

Comment: @aschipfl I need to take the value of the user's input (variable is called _username_ and I want to get a wsf script coded in VBScript to retrieve that value to insert it in a MsgBox.

Comment: Obviously, your vbs code has syntax problems, fix them first to solve your problem. You should look at the syntax of `Dim var AS STRING = VALUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use shell methods inside VBScript then use Windows Scripting Host (WSH) automation object. Please find the code:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
userName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Shared_UserName%")
WScript.Echo "Your username is: " & userName
```

See refs :[devguru.com](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-expandenvironmentstrings.html) or [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/vb/envexpand.html)

Comment: Thank you ever so much! It works flawlessly! Thank you again! :)